# Communication between contentscript, background and popup scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

On sending side : i.e from contentscript.

**contentscript.js:**

```
<script> 
    //some DOM code to obtain values to store in 'marks' array.


    //here I'm sending marks array to background.js.
    // 1) Am I sending it right?
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(marks);

</script>
```

On  receiving end : i.e in background script.*

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(MessageSender sender, function     
    sendResponse){
     /* 2) what should be here */ });
```

3) here , how can I collect(store) the array variable passed from contentscript.

4) Now,from background.js can I directly call any function in popup.js(script file
       linked to popup.html).

Can anyone please answer the above 4 questions?
 Thanks in advance!

**Inspecting my popup,gave me following error :**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**in manifest.json**

add storage permission

```
"permissions": ["storage"]
```

**in contentscript.js**

save your data in the local storage Google Chrome : [Chrome Storage API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

```
var data = ''; //set your data here
    chrome.storage.local.set({
         'myVariable': data
        });
```

use sendMessage to call the background page : [Chrome messaging API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple)

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
     greeting: "myAction"
 });
```

**in background.js**

get the message from contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "myAction") {
        collectData();
    }
 });
```

define the collectData() function

```
function collectData() {
  chrome.storage.local.get('myVariable', function (items) {
    console.log(items); //your data is on items.myVariable 
  });
}
```

**to call popup.js function from background.js use the messaging API**

Comment: Do we definitely need to store the data in local storage? Can't we store it in a variable?

Comment: @Intutisoft  I have made the suggested changes.No errors reported.But one last step, how can I pass this variable to popup.js. I'd be glad to know buddy.Thanks.

Comment: with the same principle. you get your data from the storage in the popup.js : 
chrome.storage.local.get('myVariable', function (items) {
    console.log(items); //your data is on items.myVariable 
  });

Comment: @nikhil You can not store it in a variable. Your variable scope is available only for your page. Is not possible to access to this variable from another page. So to communicate with different pages use the local storage API or send it in the Message content.

Comment: Thanks @Intuitisoft for your time, I'm getting the above error when accessing storage element .Why is that?

Comment: @nikhil learn advanced javascript and Google Chrome API. 
chrome.storage.local.get('myVariable', function (items) { marks = items.myVariable });
if you want your script works properly use the callback function to execute your next operations.