# Multiple messages in a single function call to chrome.runtime.sendMessage();

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage();
```

I want to pass multiple (to be specific 2) messages from my contentscript.js to popup.js.

I don't need other arguments for this function, I only need the `message` argument.

In my contentscript.js I have this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message1);

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message2);
```

Here is my popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(messsage1){
 //code for handling the message
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(messsage2){
 //code for handling the message
});
```

I want to combine these two functions into a single function and handle the messages like:

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(){
   // how to write the parameter for this function, I can't use ',' right?
   // code for handling the message1, message2
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

I would send the messages as JSON objects, with an additional property to specify which type of message it is. For example:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: "Message1", type: "m1"});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({content: "Message2", type: "m2"});
```

And then you can combine the message listener into one function:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  if(message.type == "m1") {
    console.log("First message: ", message.content);
  }
  if(message.type == "m2") {
    console.log("Second message: ", message.content);
  }
}
```

Of course this is just a rough example - you should tailor the structure of the JSON objects to your extension's requirements, but this is the pattern that I would use.

Answer (score 0):

**contentscript.js**

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                greeting: "message1"
            })
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                greeting: "message2"
            })
```

**popup.js**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "message1") {
        //action 1
        } else if (request.greeting == "message2") {
            //action 2
        }
    });
```

API: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: @nikki The listener is never call ?

Comment: No, it is not called. Can we hae two listeners in popup.js?

Comment: @nikki no, one is enough. When you send the message from contentscript.js, popup.js is running ?

Comment: message is actually a variable(number) should I use " " <double quotes" when calling?

Comment: Buddy, I want to pass variables actually, not just text.

Comment: Well probelm solved. I relied on Javascript String splitting rather than chrome APIs. 1)I combined two strings 2)passed it 3)splitted it into two back. Thanks @Intuitisoft for ur time.

Comment: @nikki you are welcome. Use storage API to send data [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477645/communication-between-contentscript-background-and-popup-scripts/22478730#22478730)

Answer (score 0):

runtime.sendMessage can be used only for one-time requests as per [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Consider using tabs.connect instead.

This is the code for the extension page to connect to your tab:

```
var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id);
port.postMessage({type: "first", content: "Hi!"});
port.postMessage({type: "second", content: "How are you?"});
```

And this code should be specified in the content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type == 'first') {
      ...
    }
    if (msg.type == 'second') {
      ...
    }
  });   
};
```